# Trying to use tagger with structure.. no luck

Tags: structure, devdemon-tagger

I am trying to use DevDemon's(3.21) tagger with Structure(3.3.14.5) EE (2.9)

I'm not trying to do anything fancy, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to achieve a basic list of blog entries with the same tag. My blog entries are being pulled from a structure listing.

Anytime I try anything I get an error message saying "this page doesn't exist" Obviously it's saying that because the url http://domain.com/tag/{tag_name} doesn't correspond with any page created by structure.

My blog page is using a channel entries tag.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I was wanting to use tag instead of categories because of the content fro the blog.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Freebie for this. Just create a template group called "tag" (tag.group on the filesystem) and an index.html (for listing all tags) and then another template that will pull out blog entries by tag (for example content_by_tag.html). There you can pull out whatever information from Tagger.

Then use Template Route Manager to set up a route to tag/content_by_tag on /tag/ if the url has segments after tag (the tag). See screenshot.

[image: Template Routes]

Notice "Require segments" dropdown set to Yes.

Your content_by_tag.html template can look something like this:

```
  {exp:tagger:entries_quick unitag="{segment:variable}" limit="999"}
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{tagger:entry_ids}" channel="blog" dynamic="off"}
<-- content here -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:tagger:entries}
```

In the index.html you put whatever you wish to show if the user visits the /tag/ page without a tag as the second segment. Ie. a tag cloud or something.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie) to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I am using freebie, but I can't seem to figure it out. Since structure is looking for "exact" urls any url that isn't a specific entry gets the error message. If the urls aren't being recognized by EE than tagger can't pull the correct posts.

Does that make sense?